# reverse ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, tunnel

I have an embedded device sitting out in the field, connected through a USB cell stick to the Internet. In order to be able to reach it, I establish a reverse ssh tunnel on port 19996 to my home PC to be able to access it.

Now I re-establish that tunnel every 10min (by cron), to make sure I have pretty much uninterrupted access, even when the provider decides to change my IP.

Now I realized that my process list is full of

```
"4383 root     ssh -R 19996:localhost:22 -f -N user@host"
```

and netstat is loaded up with connections as well. How can I ensure this doesn't happen? I only need one tunnel open at a time,  not 100s of them.

Comment: [Burrow.io](https://burrow.io) is a pretty cool tool for that, if what you need is HTTP or HTTPS. The free account lets you create one tunnel (HTTP), and all you gotta do in your device is run a curl command. It will even certify that the connection is always up, eliminating the need for a Cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up followiung shell script which seems to work fine!

```
#!/bin/sh
RETVAL=`netstat | grep 'S0106b0487afe2a57'| grep -c 'ssh ESTABLISHED'`
echo "${RETVAL} open tunnel(s)"
if [ "$RETVAL" -lt "1" ]
  then
        echo "starting reverse ssh tunnel"
        `ssh -R 19999:localhost:22 -f -N user@host`
        echo "done"
fi
```

Comment: I used RETVAL=`netstat | grep '<hostname>:ssh' | grep -c 'ssh ESTABLISHED'` and it seems to work OK

Answer (score 1):

use autossh instead that will reestablish the connection if it gets disconnected. try to search that in your distro's repo first and then on net if you cannot find it.

Comment: the problem iss my distribution was self assembled using buildroot (with busybox). I would need to recompile the whole baby....i'd prefer something else if i can...but good tip, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following script which a cron runs every 5mins.
Although I would expect this to work, I still find connections not allowing me in from the remote side all the time.
To answer the comment above - It doesn't appear to disappear from netstat.
I check netstat and it will still say "ssh ESTABLISHED" for the connection and so when my script runs I get the result of "sockets appear connected. assuming reverse ssh tunnel is running fine."
There must be a better way to test to the remote side and get a result which will suggest it's working ?

```
#!/bin/bash

#$Id: ssh_reverse_tunnel.sh 14 2012-10-13 22:53:21Z root $

REMOTE_USER="user"
REMOTE_DOMAIN="domain"
SOCKETS_USED=`netstat -p ssh | grep 'ssh ESTABLISHED' | grep -c $(host $REMOTE_DOMAIN | awk {'print $NF'})`

establish_connecton() {
  echo "establishing reverse ssh tunnel connection..."
  ssh -R 12222:localhost:22 -R12223:localhost:5901 -f -N -T ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_DOMAIN} &
  echo "done."
  echo
  exit
}

if [ $(ps -ef | grep "ssh -R 12222" | grep -v grep | wc -l) == 0 ]; then
  echo "no reverse ssh tunnel connection exists."
  establish_connecton
fi

if [ "$SOCKETS_USED" -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "no reverse ssh tunnel sockets are connected. nuking stale pids and re-establishing connection"
  # check for stale pids and kill them if found.
  if [ $(ps -ef | grep "ssh -R 12222" | grep -v grep | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
    # stale pids exist, kill them...
    ps -ef | grep "ssh -R 12222" | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'} | \
      while read PID; do
        echo "kill -9 $PID"
      done
  fi
  establish_connecton
else
  echo "sockets appear connected. assuming reverse ssh tunnel is running fine."
fi
```

Hope someone finds the above useful and can let me know where to build in more checks.

Answer (score 0):

Just kill the previous process (by ID) after starting the new one.  You can get the process id from the ps command.

Comment: but if i kill the existing one, a current ssh session will be terminated right? Not very convenient if i get dropped off every 10min...

Comment: Yeah, but technically there's another problem too.  A process shouldn't be able to bind to the same local port after you already have one running... so only one should be running until it gets terminated.  If you run those commands back-to-back, one should generate an error and terminate immediately... so the problem of a lot of processes doesn't seem like it should come up.  Maybe something else is happening here.  Try running them back-to-back locally from that box and see what output you get.

Comment: Well, in fact, I'm actually doing the same from my office PC here (estaablishing a reverse tunnel toi my home PC) and I get exactly the same. Here in the office, i'm running Kubuntu 12.04 so a top-noth distro that's exactly the same... :o But when establishing the tunnel, I get the error " Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 19999" but I get this on my little embedded buy as well... but it still adds a process to the process list... that's just wrong... :(

Comment: Is there a way you can check for the command failing to bind to the port at all, and terminate the hanging process if it fails?  That way, the process that is actually holding the port open will remain open and you won't lose connectivity.  Something like here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-are-the-exit-statuses-of-ssh-command/  (echo $?, and then do something based on the return code / status)

Comment: In the meantime I wrote a litttle bash script that greps for a certain foreign address and 'ssh ESTABLISHED' and if I get less than 1 connection, I re-open it. I however do not know if in case of dynamic IP change it would disappear from netstat... I assume that at least the State would change, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ssh command socket to check if the connection is still active. It should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! ssh -S mysocket -O check user@host ; then
    ssh -M -S mysocket -R 19996:localhost:22 -f -N user@host
fi
```

Then you can close that specific connection using

```
ssh -S mysocket -O exit user@host
```

It might also be worthwhile to set `ServerAliveInterval` to a value greater than 0, with `-o ServerAliveInterval=N`. As it will kill your tunnel if the connection is lost.